# Merge two mongodb documents via PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, merge, documents

I want to be able to merge two documents together, theses documents are in the same collection. For example here is the 'Master' document.

**Document One**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5640965bb23eec8d218b4a92"),
    "agencyID" : "111111",
    "paxID" : "22222",
    "bookings" : [
        {
            "bookingID": "213123",
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "tranID": "001",
                    "invoices": [
                        {
                            "invNum": "1234145",
                            "type": "i",
                            "inv_date": "20140318",
                            "inv_time": "1642",
                            "inv_val": NumberLong(81383)
                        }
                    ],
                    "tranType": "Car",
                    "tranDate": "20140318",
                    "tranTime": "2312",
                    "opCode": "ge2123",
                    "pupDate": "20140104",
                    "advPur": "13"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to merge it with a document like this

**Document Two**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5640966ab23eec8d218b4c5a"),
    "agencyID" : "22122",
    "paxID" : "-14141",
    "bookings" : [
        {
            "bookingID": "452452",
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "tranID": "002",
                    "invoices": [
                        {
                            "invNum": "2432422",
                            "type": "i",
                            "inv_date": "20141119",
                            "inv_time": "1407",
                            "inv_val": NumberLong(20840)
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So for example a PHP file would merge document '**Two**' into document '**One**', So instead of overwriting document '**One**' it adds another 'booking' onto document '**Ones**' current bookings, so when the merge is complete document '**One**' would have booking - 213123 & 452452 along with the rest of the booking information.

I hope I've explained it well enough.

EDIT -

The merge should look like this.

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5640965bb23eec8d218b4a92"),
    "agencyID" : "111111",
    "paxID" : "22222",
    "bookings" : [
        {
            "bookingID": "213123",
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "tranID": "001",
                    "invoices": [
                        {
                            "invNum": "1234145",
                            "type": "i",
                            "inv_date": "20140318",
                            "inv_time": "1642",
                            "inv_val": NumberLong(81383)
                        }
                    ],
                    "tranType": "Car",
                    "tranDate": "20140318",
                    "tranTime": "2312",
                    "opCode": "ge2123",
                    "pupDate": "20140104",
                    "advPur": "13"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
        "bookingID": "452452",
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "tranID": "002",
                    "invoices": [
                        {
                            "invNum": "2432422",
                            "type": "i",
                            "inv_date": "20141119",
                            "inv_time": "1407",
                            "inv_val": NumberLong(20840)
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show how the merged should look like?

Comment: @user3100115 I think i got my JSON correct, check my edit.

Comment: how to identify the two documents you want to merge in your collection?